# Setting paypal for mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, paypal

I have created paypal button with this code

```
   <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

          <!-- Order id. -->
          <input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="'+paypalData.orderId+'" />

          <!-- Specify a PayPal Shopping Cart Add to Cart button. -->
          <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
          <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">

          <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
          <input type="hidden" name="business" value="'+paypalData.businessId+'">

          <!-- Specify currency. -->
          <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="'+paypalData.currency+'">

          <!-- The URL to which PayPal posts information about the payment, in the form of Instant Payment -->
          <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="notify">
          <!-- Return URL when cancel payment -->
          <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="cancel">
          <!-- Return URL when payment is done -->
          <input type="hidden" name="return" value="return">


          <input type="hidden" name="amount_'+index+'" value="'+val["price_per_unit"]+'">
          <input type="hidden" name="quantity_'+index+'" value="'+val["count"]+'">
          <input type="hidden" name="item_name_'+index+'" value="'+val["name"]+'">



          <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="'+paypalData.submitAlt+'">
          <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
   </form>
```

But I need to modify it for jQuery mobile. I know that I have to use this command:

cmd=_express-checkout-mobile in url https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout-mobile

but I dont know how to use it and where to put it.

Whole aplication is converted by phonegap.

Thank you very much for your time and any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Your current integration is using [PayPal Standard](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/wp_standard_overview/).  [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/) is part of the [API products](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/).  You would need to rebuild your checkout using the API to take advantage of Express Checkout.